# Can a "crash landing" be used for FAR 61.57 currency?

Tags: faa-regulations, landing, accidents, currency

FAR 61.57 (a) requires that one must make 3 takeoffs and landings within the preceding 90 days in order to carry passengers.

Does a "crash landing" count for the 61.57 currency? By "crash landing" I mean a landing on which an incident/accident occurs under the NTSB definitions.

For example, if I'm in the circuit to gain 61.57 currency, and on my 3rd landing attempt, I crash the aircraft into a tree well short of the runway. Would I then be allowed to go rent another aircraft and carry a passenger?

Comment: In this case you'll definitely have greater problems than your currency. I'm not sure, that's why I don't write an answers,  but in my eyes a crash is some kind of landing - only by definition and without any evaluation. Maybe it can even be used to remain current,  but you might don't even have to worry about your currency after this kind of incident.

Comment: @Falk I agree, I just think it's an interesting hypothetical question. Obviously if that happened to me, currency would be the last thing on my mind.

Comment: Perhaps a better example (which doesn't immediately call your piloting ability into question) would be if the landing gear folds on touchdown or something?

Comment: @roe Really not much difference in the hours following the crash from a legal perspective.  (In your case though, you probably wouldn't get the follow-up-reexamination-letter bit so would be simpler over-all.)

Comment: @Lnafziger; true, but using "parking in a tree" as an example seems to have drawn the attention away from the actual question :)

Comment: @roe Maybe, but determining fault is tricky, so what about the questions in the middle where the investigation has to determine "fault"?  That takes awhile....  That's why they have the process that they do and don't just suspend your license on the spot!

Comment: This is the most awesome question I've ever seen on an aviation Q&A site. Bravo... +1!

Comment: Be aware that for night currency, the crash landing must be to a complete stop.

Comment: @falstro.  I have folded a landing gear on landing with a subsequent chewing up of prop.  Heavens yes, I logged it as a landing, it being a far more interesting and instructive experience than the majority of my other landings.

Comment: Any landing you can walk away from...

Comment: If you logged 3 good landings then crashed, yes.  If you logged 2, then hit a tree short of the runway, then no.  See how easy that was?!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As far as I can find, the FAA doesn't define the term *landing* so it could be argued either way.  The "typical" [definition of landing](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/landing) is:

> **1:** an act or process of one that lands; especially :  a going or bringing
> to a surface (as land or shore) after a voyage or flight

That definition doesn't say that it has to be "controlled" or that the airplane has to be usable again!  Even if you decide that it wasn't a "successful landing", you could always get your third landing later if you are still allowed to fly, and then carry the passengers.

---

So this brings us to the second part of your question:  Are you allowed to fly after an accident?

Since you had an accident (as defined by [49 CFR 830](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?tpl=/ecfrbrowse/Title49/49cfr830_main_02.tpl)) you must immediately notify the NTSB of the accident.  Once you do that, you have 10 days to file the required report.

At this point, you still have a valid pilot license and can legally fly another airplane.

Chances are however, that you will be receiving a certified letter from the local FSDO requiring a *reexamination* in order to keep your license because your competence has been called into question.  If you don't call them to make an appointment, they will start the process to suspend your certificate.  During this time, you can also continue to fly because you still have a valid license.

The FAA can also use their emergency authority to immediately suspend your license if they feel that it is warranted.  This can be appealed to the NTSB if you feel that it isn't justified, and they have up to five days to respond.  At this point you are not allowed to fly pending the response from the board.

---

This, and a lot more information can be found on [AOPA's FAA Enforcement Webpage](http://www.aopa.org/Pilot-Resources/PIC-archive/FAA-Enforcement/FAA-Enforcement.aspx).

Comment: A §49.709 re-examination would require sufficient evidence of gross incompetency or negligence on the part of the aviator.  The circumstances of the landing would have to be reviewed and may or may not warrant that.  An emergency revocation of an airman certificate would imply an INTENTIONAL act of reckless behavior.