# Is it still "landing" in a seaplane?

Tags: landing, terminology, seaplane

This probably sounds like a silly question, but I was watching floatplanes land on Lake Union, Seattle, and it got me wondering whether a plane that touches down onto water is still talked about as "landing" in aviation parlance.

Is it?

Comment: To be fair, you (the pilot) do end up on land *eventually*...  Well, unless you're flying an MVP.Aero, then maybe not...

Comment: Well sure, but you don't call driving home "bedding" since you end up in bed at the end of the day.

Comment: It's a watering.

Comment: I think if you said "watering" you'd get some funny looks and/or some good laughs.

Comment: I propose "Splashdown"

Comment: Added a tag USA, as in my language there are two distinct words, and using landing on water would be very fun.

Comment: You park on a driveway and you drive on a parkway. Isn't English weird?

Comment: Also, you can carry cargo by ships and shipment by cars.

Comment: I'm not sure [USA] is appropriate, [English], maybe, but I don't see any Canadians or Brits chiming in with non-AmE answers.

Comment: @JanDvorak "Get on the plane? F*** you. I'm getting IN the plane." -George Carlin

Comment: Is it any more odd than "sailing" a ship powered by steam or diesel instead of sails?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes. One 'official' example is from the FAA's [test standards](https://www.faa.gov/training_testing/testing/test_standards/media/FAA-S-8081-14B.pdf) for land and seaplanes, which includes these tasks for seaplanes:

> Task H: Glassy Water Approach and Landing
>   [...]
>   Task J: Rough Water
>   Approach and Landing

The FAA's *[Seaplane, Skiplane, and Float/Ski Equipped Helicopter Operations Handbook](https://www.faa.gov/regulations_policies/handbooks_manuals/aviation/seaplane_handbook/)* also uses it; Chapter 6 is called "Seaplane Operations - Landings".

Interestingly, the word "landing" itself isn't defined in the FAA's [glossary](http://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/media/pcg.pdf) or in [14 CFR 1.1](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?rgn=div8&node=14:1.0.1.1.1.0.1.1) (the US air regulations general definitions). Presumably it's considered to be too 'obvious' to require a definition.

Comment: Haha, related to the landing definition: [Can a “crash landing” be used for FAR 61.57 currency?](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/1170/69)

Comment: In more logical languages than English, no. In German it is "wassern" while landing on land is "landen".

Comment: @PeterKämpf Yes, Spanish is another one: aterrizar vs. amerizar.

Comment: English doesn't stand alone though. Dutch also doesn't have a specific word for it and merely calls it a "landing" (or "noodlanding" for "emergency landing", which still isn't limited to water). And in German, while as mentioned the word wassern/Wasserung does exist, the use of the more general word landen/Landung would not be wrong, a Wasserung is a specific type of Landung.

Comment: So, you land a seaplane to get from air to water, and then you land it again when you sail it to a dock?

Comment: ... then you land it the third time when you pull it onto a truck and drive it to its owner?

Answer (score 10):

Not in French it isn't. French for landing is 'aterrir' which roughly translates to 'return to the land'. Using this verb for a sea 'landing' would sound silly to them so they use 'amerrir' which means 'return to the sea' (Mer being French for sea, terre is French for ground). A landing in the Moon would be 'alunir'.

This interesting fact was mentioned by the instructor on my French audio course.

Comment: A landing on any planet or satellite, or on an asteroid, will still be *un atterrissage* (a landing), as *atterrir* (to land) is not returning to Earth (*la Terre*), but to the ground (*le sol*). The neologisms *alunissage* and *alunir* (Moon landing, to land on the Moon), which are frequently used, [have been in fact rejected by the *Académie française*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alunissage#Vocabulaire). That matches with English use, as in [the Eagle has landed](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Eagle%20has%20Landed) (Apollo 11).

Answer (score 4):

No. ICAO defines a landing like this:

> From the beginning of the landing flare until aircraft exits the landing **runway**, comes to a stop on the **runway**, or when power is applied for takeoff in the case of a touch-and-go landing.

([source](http://www.intlaviationstandards.org/Documents/PhaseofFlightDefinitions.pdf))

And a runway like this:

> A defined rectangular area **on a land aerodrome** prepared for the landing and take-off of aircraft

([source](http://www.icao.int/safety/implementation/library/manual%20aerodrome%20stds.pdf))

Wikipedia suggests that "landing" on water is referred to as "alighting"

Comment: Does ICAO define "alighting"?

Comment: Not as far as I can tell. However, the following document contains this definition: "water alighting area: means a suitable stretch of water for the landing or taking-off   of   a   float   plane   under   specific conditions" - http://www.icao.int/APAC/Meetings/2016%20WASWG2/!IP%2001%20-%20Water%20aerodromes%20requirements.pdf

Comment: Haha, by definition they exclude "landing" on water, but then specifically refer to landing when talking about what a float plane does on water?  Classic!

Comment: Indeed hehe .. not very well thought through

Comment: So what is it called when you deliberately and controlledly put an airplane on solid ground after a flight in the same way that you would land, but you don't do it on a runway?